# swift: functional programming & arrays

Tags: swift

```
var data: [[String]] = ...
let pos = data.compactMap { Int($0[posColumn]) }
let neg = data.compactMap { Int($0[negColumn]) }

let sum = ?? { pos + neg }
```

I have a csv data, a column for positive values and a column for negative. Using `data.compactMap` I get two arrays for both. How can I get `[Int]` for `sum` using functional programming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to sum across your two columns to create a third column.

Use [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip) to combine the arrays and [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/enumeratedsequence/2907233-map) to sum them:

```
let sum = zip(pos, neg).map(+)
```

---

> what if I need to get sum AND divide by some number? So, there will be
>   3 arrays: pos, neg, tot. (pos + neg) / tot

Since `zip` only works with 2 sequences, you could instead `map` over the indices of one of your arrays:

```
let result = pos.indices.map { (pos[$0] + neg[$0]) / tot[$0] }
```

Comment: Yes! To make it more complex: what if I need to get sum AND divide by some number? So, there will be 3 arrays: pos, neg, tot. (pos + neg) / tot

Comment: As tot is an array with corresponding values, it should be like: let result = zip(pos, neg, tot).map { ($0 + $1)/$2 } - but zip takes only 2 args.

Comment: Oh, in that case `let result = pos.indices.map { (pos[$0] + neg[$0]) / tot[$0] }`

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = (pos + neg).reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: This code-only answer would be better if it explained why the code works.

Comment: @jkdev you mean I should mention how this code works?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would make the answer easier to understand, and more valuable for other people who find it.